# Flex. Images aligning in htmlText

Tags: apache-flex, htmltext

I set **htmlText** property of a **TextArea** to the following value:

```
<img src="img.gif" />Some text<br><img src="img.gif" />Some text
```

The top edge of "Some text" is aligned to the top edge of the corresponging image.

How to align it by **bottom** edges (the bottom of the text to the bottom of the image)? Is it possible?

Remark: image's height is greater than text's one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the solutions is to use [a Canvas over the TextArea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/790460/flex3-canvas-over-textarea)

Answer (score 1):

Try this in the HTML text -

```
<table> <tr> <td> <img src="c:\1.png"/> </td> <td VALIGN="bottom"> Some text </td> </tr> </table
```

Comment: Unfortunately, table tag is not supported in Flex renderer.